# Read Json Serialized c#

Tags: c#, json, mvvm

I am trying to get the id from this json text. I'm not sure how to go about getting it doesn't let me create a json object. I tried deserializing it doing this:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetIdAsync(string username)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceURL);

    var  Id  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

   return Id;
}
```

but I get this error during the deserialization

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered
>   while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 2

this is the json text:

```
json    "[{\"Id\":1,\"FirstName\":\"a\",\"LastName\":\"b\",\"UserName\":\"user\",\"Email\":\"d@gmail.com\",\"Password\":\"poSsUrscOuXL+E5qxXsCsA==\",\"CompanyName\":\"c\",\"Salt\":\"n3ZLSwU9L1g=\",\"Address\":{\"Country\":\"c\",\"Province\":\"p\",\"City\":\"c\",\"PostalCode\":\"p\",\"Street\":\"street\",\"StreetNumber\":\"123\"},\"Telephone\":{\"PersonalPhoneNumber\":\"413414\",\"BusinessPhoneNumber\":\"134134\"},\"Location\":{\"Lat\":45.6025839,\"Lng\":-97.8489959}}]"   string
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given value of provided JSON which is an array of objects. You can use dynamic object to extract just the property you want. First deserialize the json to a `List<dynamic>`, get the first object in the list and call the `Id` property.

```
public async Task<int> GetIdAsync(string username) {
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceURL);

    var list  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(json);

    var obj = list.FirstOrDefault();

    int Id = obj != null ? obj.Id : 0;

    return Id;
}
```

UPDATE:

Tested it in a simple unit test and passes as expected.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest6 {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetIdAsyncTest() {

        var id = await GetIdAsync("");

        Assert.IsTrue(id > o);
    }

    public async Task<int> GetIdAsync(string username) {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        //simple data just for the purpose of the test.
        var json = await Task.FromResult("[{\"Id\":1,\"FirstName\":\"a\"}]"); //await httpClient.GetStringAsync("");

        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(json);

        var obj = list.FirstOrDefault();

        int Id = obj != null ? obj.Id : 0;

        return Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey I get an error: at the before last step of the operation this Unhandled Exception:



Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for `Id'

Comment: the first or default on the list basically did nothing

Comment: I tested it in a unit test and it returned a result without any error.

Comment: well its because i changed all the int? to int. Is there a reason why you need the question mark im not familiar with this?

Comment: `int?` means `Nullable<int>`. changed it to allow the method to indicate if no id was found. if a valid id was found the method would return it in the value otherwise null. So a null result meant that an id was not found.

Comment: is it possible to change it to int because your making me have to change it everywhere in all the classes of the project from int to int?

Comment: Alright. let me look for a work around. So what if you don't get an Id. what result would you want? 0 (zero)?

Comment: theres literally no way you can't get an id from this thats the thing because its iterating through the dB entries. Also I tried putting the int/int? and obj contain the same as what list contains which is the json text. I swear firstordefault is not working on my end. obj and list are equal

Comment: Not if you are returning a list. first or default returns a single object or null if the list is empty.

Comment: okay first or default returns an object but im just trying to extract the id portion of this object which the 1

Comment: That's exactly what `obj.Id` is doing.

Comment: when i type obj. theres no property called id. the id is the primary key found in the dB

Comment: dynamic objects dont have intellisense. The properties are realized at run time. Just make sure it matches the name of the property in the json.

Comment: My suggestion was basically a workaround to avoid having to create a new strongly typed object just to extract one property value.

Comment: I mean I would love for this to work as it is much simpler as the other option but I just want this to work either way :). The program just crashes everytime at int id = obj.Id;

Comment: And it works when tested as is above. Have you excluded some information that I an unaware of that is making it fail when you try it? Otherwise we'll just keep going back and forth. My answer is based on the information provided in original post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129084/discussion-between-jayphillips-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model of your Json file using http://json2csharp.com/ :

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public Telephone Telephone { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Telephone
{
    public string PersonalPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string BusinessPhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public float Lat { get; set; }
    public float Lng { get; set; }
}
```

---

And then deserialize it like that :

```
public async Task<int> GetIdAsync(string username)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceURL);

        var  Id  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json).Property1.FirstOrDefault().Id;
```

;

```
       return Id;
};
```

---

Update after @JayPhillips who wish to have the "real" json file:

```
[
   {
      "Id":1,
      "FirstName":"a",
      "LastName":"b",
      "UserName":"user",
      "Email":"d@gmail.com",
      "Password":"poSsUrscOuXL+E5qxXsCsA==",
      "CompanyName":"c",
      "Salt":"n3ZLSwU9L1g=",
      "Address":{
         "Country":"c",
         "Province":"p",
         "City":"c",
         "PostalCode":"p",
         "Street":"street",
         "StreetNumber":"123"
      },
      "Telephone":{
         "PersonalPhoneNumber":"413414",
         "BusinessPhoneNumber":"134134"
      },
      "Location":{
         "Lat":45.6025839,
         "Lng":-97.8489959
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: *"You should create a model of your Json file using ..."* ... you *can* ;-), there are other great sources where you can do this and visual studio has a build in feature for it.

Comment: @Jim Is it an addon to visual studio ?

Comment: it's build in ... copy some json and `Edit > Paste special > Paste JSON As Classes`

Comment: I tried highlighting and copying my  text i posted in the original post before following pasting as json classses but it says I have an error: the content in the clipboard isnt a valid instance JSON instance

Comment: @JayPhillips the json in your question is escaped with  \ , you need the valid *real* json ...

Comment: how? I thought this was the real one

Comment: I ve updated my reply if you want to get the json file without '\, it will be readable with : httpClient.GetStringAsync and you will be able to create the Json Class with Visual Studio like suggest @Jim